# Why does Startup Repair run regularly and finds no problems?

Tags: windows-vista, boot

My Windows Vista computer regularly runs Startup Repair on bootup. It does not let me cancel. My computer will not turn off using the power button (I haven't tried unplugging it during this process).  This takes 5-10 minutes.  It finds no problems. Then it reboots and runs fine.

Most of the time it boots normally.  But it has done this ten times or more.  How can I avoid this waste of time?   Is there something wrong with my software or hardware?

Comment: Windows seems to think there's a fault with your installation. This can usually be traced to a hardware problem, most probably caused by a faulty power supply or hard drive. I'd have both of those checked for problems.

Answer (score -1):

if this program is inside of windows then you should be able to remove it in start up programs with the help of msconfig
if it is running during the boot process before going into windows, then you need to look at your computer setup, usually you have press f12 or f something to get into setup, the key should be displayed during the boot process

Comment: This is not correct. Startup Repair happens before Windows boots to the desktop.